# Stream function for 2D stokeslet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, potential, flow, navier-stokes

I'm trying to find a source that gives the stream function for a 2D stokeslet.  A stokeslet is a solution to unbounded Stokes flow with a point singularity at the origin.  I know [the velocity field induced by a 2D stokeslet](https://doi.org/10.1137/S106482750038146X) ([pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247931625_The_Method_of_Regularized_Stokeslets)) at point $\bf{x}$ is

$$ u({\bf x}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \mu} \left(- {\bf F} \ln|{\bf x}| + ({\bf F} \cdot {\bf x}) \frac{\bf x}{|{\bf x}|^2} \right). \tag{13}$$

where $\bf{F}$ is a point force acting on the fluid at the origin and $\mu$ is the fluid viscosity.

I also know that for a 2D stream function $\psi$ [you can get the velocity field](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/stream-function-psi) by doing:

$$ u_x=-\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}, \qquad u_y=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}. $$

However it's not obvious to me how to find a $\psi$ that will produce the velocity field corresponding to the stokeslet and I can't find a source that gives a stream function for the stokeslet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\psi~=~\frac{1}{4\pi\mu}\det[{\bf F},{\bf x}](\ln|{\bf x}|-1). $$

Comment: That's quite the hint!  Is there a source for that, or can you give a derivation?

Comment: Well, let me first ask you this: Can you confirm that it is a solution?

Comment: I'm working on it now but my vector calculus is a little rusty.  Oh!, I should say this isn't for school or anything, I'm trying to learn this on my own.

Comment: Okay, I've verified that the corresponding velocity field is the same as the stokeslet.  I had to break it in to components to get there, but I suspect there's a straightforward derivation?

Comment: Well, integration is more difficult than differentiation.

Comment: Right, so how did you come up with the stream function?  Did you do the integration, guess at what it might look like and verify, or is there a reference work you pulled it from?

Comment: Somewhere in between integrating and guessing.